# Enforce Visual Studio exception handling mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

I'm using the Visual Studio /EHsc exception handling mode in my project. This means catch(...) won't catch structured exceptions. I've got a public header that does a catch(...) that can be included by consumer projects.

I'm concerned that a project consuming my header may have a different exception handling mode that will make my header misbehave.

Is there a way of static_asserting or #pragma error'ing or otherwise failing the build if the exception handling mode isn't as needed?

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

> _CPPUNWIND Defined as 1 if one or more of the /GX (Enable Exception Handling), /clr (Common Language Runtime Compilation), or /EH
>   (Exception Handling Model) compiler options are set. Otherwise,
>   undefined.

It's not perfect, but it gives you a fighting chance to get them the same